# Vendor changed the certificate, my client .Net application started failing with the HAndshake Failure

Tags: .net, encryption, tls1.2, handshake

My client .net 3.5 application(TLs v1.2) started failing from the time service vendor updated the certificate at their end. Certificate use was optional, and we were not using it and hence we did not think that it will impact us.
But as soon as they updated the certificate my client application started failing.
Its a handshake failure which I am facing right now - 
I got the logs from the vendor and it doesn't give me any details about the error.

Failure logs from the vendor is this:

Apr  5 17:30:06 localhost haproxy[xxx]: xx.xx.xxx.xxxx:43812 [05/Apr/2018:17:30:06.912] xxx.xxx3.com/2: SSL handshake failure

I tried to run the code locally and could run it without any issues.
Successful handshake log from the vendor is as follows:

Apr  6 12:08:54 localhost haproxy[19307]: xxx.xxx3.com appsjavadev_cluster/appsjavadev1 client_ip:xx.xx.xxx.xxxx client_port:23413 SSL_version:TLSv1.2 SSL_cypher:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 -- 287/0/2/10/299 200 285 - - --NI 74/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /JSIUploadB2B/serve.xml HTTP/1.1"

Vendor team is suggesting that we are using the wrong cipher for the communication and that's the reason of the failure. 
But I do not know how to change that from my client. Is it a server setting I need to do? Or somewhere in my .Net code I need to force the Cipher technique which my client would be using.

I have broken my head already on this for almost a week now as its failing on all dev, qa and production server from almost a week now. Tried to see multiple threads but nothing provided exact solution to my problem.

Any help?

Thank you..

Edited:
 Accepted cipher suites:

## TLS 1.2

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  256

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  256

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS 256

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  128

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS  128

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS 128

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 112

Comment: Though the answer below might not address the issue you met, you do need a tool like Wireshark to check the handshake packets and identify why the error happens (due to which ciphers). Only then you can start to think about a solution. Right now, the cause is not clear yet.

Comment: @LexLi For what reasons does my answer not address the issue?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark 1) The question does not contain OS information. Your suggestion does not cover that either. Then the claim of ".NET doesn't support" or "these aren't supported in .NET by default" is weak. 2) The suggestion on "update your .NET application to use newer cipher suites" is also broad (though Google should tell). 3) The suggestion on Bouncy Castle is also broad (another time to use Google). 4) "AFAIK, there are no plans to update them anytime soon, but I might be wrong." .NET Core moves quickly, but .NET Framework (especially 3.5) is not. You should leave them as comments.

Comment: @LexLi I don't understand how a suggestion to modify your existing to code to support newer TLS suites, and then suggesting a library that allows you to do so, is broad.  Additionally, neither .NET Core nor any version of the .NET framework supports AES-GCM, I don't see how commenting on this is wrong/broad.  I thought it was relatively well known how far behind Microsoft are when it comes to their crypto implementations.

Comment: `System.Security.Cryptography` might not have AES-GCM yet, as discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7023), but a .NET Core app can use AES-GCM ciphers for TLS 1.2 as [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/15157) confirmed (it works also on my machine). Even .NET Framework 4.x apps can use AES-GCM ciphers due to the recent changes in new releases.

Comment: @LexLi Can you cite these recent changes?  I can't get it to work on .NET 4.x.

Comment: Microsoft makes it not easy to find the exact source on Windows/.NET Framework changes (.NET Framework "What's new" does not explicitly mention such). Either you build lab environment to test it out, or use their support service to get a detailed answer.

Comment: You haven't shown any code, haven't said what the difference between the certificates is, and haven't shown what ciphersuites are supported by the client and the server. Makes it hard to answer the question.

Comment: A .NET 3.5 program will not use TLSv1.2, that option did not become available until version 4.5.  Easy to see when you review the acceptable values for SecurityPointManager.SecurityProtocol property.  If you can't convince that server that SSL3 is acceptable (few still think it is, given the POODLE attack vulnerability) then you need to update.